# How to customize an NSTableView row draggingImage?

Tags: nstableview

Currently when I drag out a row from an NSTableView it is semi-transparent text in the row. Instead I would like to show a semi-transparent image representing this row.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest overriding either `-[NSTableView dragImageForRowsWithIndexes:tableColumns:event:offset:]` (available since OS X 10.4) or the `draggingImageComponents` property of `NSTableCellView` (available since OS X 10.7, for the new view-based table views).

Comment: `draggingImageComponents` is not called in my `NSTableCellView` subclass

Comment: For the usage of -draggingImageComponents see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586110/custom-drag-image-with-nstableview-as-drag-source/30213507#30213507