# How to make a drag & drop for NSTableCellView like this

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstablecellview

I'm trying to implement a drag & drop for `NSTableCellView` look like screenshot, but the only thing i can do just the text, not a whole cell like screenshot bellow :(

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Drag and Drop Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragsource.html)

> The Dragged Image
>
> The image that is dragged in a dragging session is simply an image
>   that represents the data on the pasteboard. Although a dragging
>   destination can access the image, its primary concern is with the
>   pasteboard data that the image represents—the dragging operation that
>   a destination ultimately performs is on the pasteboard data, not on
>   the image itself.

See [Custom drag image with NSTableView as drag source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586110/custom-drag-image-with-nstableview-as-drag-source)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for my question :)

NSView to NSImage: [link](https://gist.github.com/shpakovski/7696268)

Override `draggingImageComponents` in `NSTableCellView` subclass

```
-(NSArray *) draggingImageComponents{
    self.layer.opacity = 0.5;
    NSImage *image = [self imageRepresentation];
    self.layer.opacity = 1;

    NSDraggingImageComponent *draggingImage = [NSDraggingImageComponent draggingImageComponentWithKey:@"background"];
    draggingImage.contents = image;
    draggingImage.frame = self.bounds;
    return @[draggingImage];
}
```